# SwiftUI JSON won't print title in ScrollView HStack (but will in List)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am getting errors in my ContentView.swift file, and as I am trying to learn I am not understanding what the errors are saying.

I get that it can't assign the value of type Program to the type Post but how am I meant to get the title?

How can I get this to print in HStack?

[image: error]

```
import SwiftUI
import RemoteImage

struct ContentView: View {
  
    @State var posts: [Program] = []
    
   var body: some View {
    List(posts){ post in
        
        Text("hello")
        
        /*RemoteImage(type: .url(URL(string:post.url)!), errorView: { error in
            Text(error.localizedDescription)
        }, imageView: { image in
            image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }, loadingView: {
            Text("Loading ...")
        })*/
        
        
       // UrlImageView(post.url)
        } .onAppear {
           Api().getPosts { (posts) in
                            self.posts = posts
                           }
                    }
    

    
   
     
        }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

// Add this top level struct to
// decode properly
struct Post: Codable {
    var programs: [Program]
}

struct Program: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title : String
    var icon : String
}

class Api {
    // Update this to return an array of Program
    func getPosts(completion: @escaping ([Program]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/programs/DRN1") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            // Based on the updated structs, you would no
            // longer be decoding an array
            let post = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                // The array is stored under programs now
                completion(post.programs)
            }
            
        }
    .resume()
    }
}
```

Also this does work but it is not scrollable.

```
  ForEach(posts){ post in
                  HStack {Text(post.title)}
               }.onAppear{
                   Api().getPosts { (posts) in
                       self.posts = posts
                   }
               }
```

to be clear the end result I am trying to get is this.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack(spacing: 20) {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Text("Item \($0)")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clean and build the project. The code seems to work fine.
I've created a new project and simply copied & pasted the above code that you've written and it is working correctly.

EDITED -
To show the list horizontally, please use below code:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        if posts.isEmpty {
            Text("Loading")
        } else {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(posts) { post in
                        return Text(post.title)
                    }
                }
            }.frame(height: 200)
        }
    }.onAppear {
        Api().getPosts { (posts) in
            self.posts = posts
        }
    }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
}
```

Comment: yes But now try and put it in a HStack and it fails. As I need it to be an a ScrollView { HStack{
(DATA HERE)
}}

Comment: Do it like this: HStack {Text(post.title)}
Its working, I've tested it.

Comment: And yes if you do 

  ForEach(posts){ post in
                  HStack {Text(post.title)}
               }.onAppear{
                   Api().getPosts { (posts) in
                       self.posts = posts
                   }
               }

It works but not scrollable

Comment: Replace your ContentView's body with
List(posts){ post in
            HStack {
                Text(post.title)
            }
        } .onAppear {
            Api().getPosts { (posts) in
                self.posts = posts
            }
        }

Comment: Thats not what HStack is meant to do More like:

ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack(spacing: 20) {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Text("Item \($0)")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}

Comment: So, do you want to display all the post title horizontally?

Comment: Well eventually it will be images but I just wanted to get the titles working first - If I can get that working I can get images working

Comment: @RussellHarrower I've updated the above answer. Please try with the above code in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I think I now understand. You need to run any onAppear before the View body loads aka the navigation section.