# Swift UI fetching JSON

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, jsondecoder

So I need to fetch the following JSON

```
{"programs":[{"_id":"5d6b3e82bbe890f60cd0e4be","title":"3TO","link":"http://radiomedia.com.au","icon":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/ttto/3TO.jpg","banner":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/ttto/TTTO%20-%20BANNER.jpg","url":"ttto","station":["DRN1"],"category":"Comedy","description":"This That The Other (3TO) focuses on all things Pop Culture. Join Harry and Matt as they dive into some of your favourite things.","subtitle":"3TO everything from pop culture to movies to anything that is interesting","summary":"3TO everything from pop culture to movies to anything that is interesting","explicit":"no","active":true,"itunes_link":"https://podcasts.apple.com/au/podcast/3to/id1478540231","stitcher_link":"https://www.stitcher.com/s?fid=460120&refid=stpr","googlepodcast":"https://playmusic.app.goo.gl/?ibi=com.google.PlayMusic&isi=691797987&ius=googleplaymusic&apn=com.google.android.music&link=https://play.google.com/music/m/Ieckipkqa2umkhasjarwu37omxe?t%3D3TO%26pcampaignid%3DMKT-na-all-co-pr-mu-pod-16"},{"_id":"5db6dc57c170710eb0e275df","title":"Fresh7@7","link":"http://drn1.com.au/shows/fresh7at7","icon":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/fresh7at7/fresh7at7icon.jpg","banner":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/fresh7at7/Fresh7%407BANNER.jpg","url":"fresh7at7","station":["DRN1"],"category":"Music","description":"Descrover the hottest indie music each week from around the world","subtitle":"Descrover the hottest indie music each week from around the world","summary":"Descrover the hottest indie music each week from around the world","explicit":"no","active":true,"itunes_link":"","stitcher_link":""},{"_id":"5e27cd3f4344393d8cd6a105","title":"Open Bar","link":"http://drn1.com.au/shows/openbar","icon":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/OpenBar/Open%20Bar-Logo.png","banner":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/OpenBar/OpenBarBanner.png","url":"openbar","category":"Arts","subcategory":"Food","description":"Join Blake, Paul &amp; Nathan each week as they discuss all things beer, wine and spirits. As well as drinking they get to sit down with brewers from around Australia and the world and talk about the industries that inventions.","subtitle":"Join Blake, Paul &amp; Nathan each week as they discuss all things beer, wine and spirits. As well as drinking they get to sit down with brewers from around Australia and the world and talk about the industries that inventions.","summary":"Join Blake, Paul &amp; Nathan each week as they discuss all things beer, wine and spirits. As well as drinking they get to sit down with brewers from around Australia and the world and talk about the industries that inventions.","explicit":"no","station":["DRN1"],"day-air":["Tuesday"],"starttime-air":"18:00:00","endtime-air":"19:00:00","active":true,"itunes_link":"https://podcasts.apple.com/au/podcast/open-bar/id1495927932","stitcher_link":"https://www.stitcher.com/podcast/radio-media-pty-ltd-2/open-bar-2","googlepodcast":"https://playmusic.app.goo.gl/?ibi=com.google.PlayMusic&isi=691797987&ius=googleplaymusic&apn=com.google.android.music&link=https://play.google.com/music/m/I4idsbtya256jrywrq2e7owwg6u?t%3DOpen_Bar%26pcampaignid%3DMKT-na-all-co-pr-mu-pod-16"},{"_id":"5e523b7f0cbaca2dec513419","title":"Behind The Goals","link":"http://drn1.com.au/shows/btg","icon":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/behindthegoals/BTGLogo.png","banner":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/behindthegoals/BTGBanner.png","url":"btg","category":"Sports","subcategory":"","description":"Join John and Anthony every Sunday morning to  get your AFL fix. It's the footy show where we review all the games of the weekend and preview the remaining games on a Sunday. You'll get stats, news and banter but most of all, you'll get lots of fantasy football talk.","subtitle":"Join John and Anthony every Sunday morning to  get your AFL fix. It's the footy show where we review all the games of the weekend and preview the remaining games on a Sunday. You'll get stats, news and banter but most of all, you'll get lots of fantasy football talk.","summary":"Join John and Anthony every Sunday morning to  get your AFL fix. It's the footy show where we review all the games of the weekend and preview the remaining games on a Sunday. You'll get stats, news and banter but most of all, you'll get lots of fantasy football talk.","explicit":"no","station":["DRN1"],"day-air":["Sunday"],"starttime-air":"10:00:00","endtime-air":"12:00:00","active":true,"itunes_link":"https://podcasts.apple.com/au/podcast/behind-the-goals/id1500174427","stitcher_link":"https://www.stitcher.com/podcast/radio-media-pty-ltd-2/behind-the-goals-2","googlepodcast":"https://playmusic.app.goo.gl/?ibi=com.google.PlayMusic&isi=691797987&ius=googleplaymusic&apn=com.google.android.music&link=https://play.google.com/music/m/Iq7oa3hezzknb4plm7m3r7tfamq?t%3DBehind_The_Goals%26pcampaignid%3DMKT-na-all-co-pr-mu-pod-16"},{"_id":"5e57a0380a55a21d804186eb","title":"El Ritmo De Vero","link":"http://drn1.com.au/shows/erdv","icon":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/ElritmodeVero/El%20ritmo%20de%20Vero.png","banner":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/ElritmodeVero/El%20ritmo%20de%20Vero-banner.png","url":"erdv","category":"Music","subcategory":"","description":"Nica Vero brings your an hour of latin music for your enjoyment every Thursday LIVE on DRN1 and replayed for our Spain listeners at 3pm local time (10pm Perth time)","subtitle":"Nica Vero brings your an hour of latin music for your enjoyment every Thursday LIVE on DRN1 and replayed for our Spain listeners at 3pm local time (10pm Perth time)","summary":"Nica Vero brings your an hour of latin music for your enjoyment every Thursday LIVE on DRN1 and replayed for our Spain listeners at 3pm local time (10pm Perth time)","explicit":"no","station":["DRN1"],"day-air":["Thursday"],"starttime-air":["10:00:00","22:00:00"],"endtime-air":["11:00:00","23:00:00"],"active":true,"itunes_link":"","stitcher_link":""},{"_id":"5e5b6caf0a55a21d804186f6","title":"Midday Marketing With Lynn","link":"http://drn1.com.au/shows/middaymarketing","icon":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/middaymarketing/logo.png","banner":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/middaymarketing/Midday%20Marketing%20Banner.png","url":"middaymarketing","category":"Business","subcategory":"Marketing","description":"Join marketing guru Lynn Loganathan each Sunday @ Midday for Midday Marketing. Where she sits down and has a chat to people in business and marketing. Each week Lynn and her guests give you some useful tips and tricks to making the most our of your marketing dollars.","subtitle":"Join marketing guru Lynn Loganathan each Sunday @ Midday for Midday Marketing. Where she sits down and has a chat to people in business and marketing. Each week Lynn and her guests give you some useful tips and tricks to making the most our of your marketing dollars.","summary":"Join marketing guru Lynn Loganathan each Sunday @ Midday for Midday Marketing. Where she sits down and has a chat to people in business and marketing. Each week Lynn and her guests give you some useful tips and tricks to making the most our of your marketing dollars.","explicit":"no","station":["DRN1"],"day-air":["Sunday"],"starttime-air":["12:00:00"],"endtime-air":["13:00:00"],"active":true,"itunes_link":"https://podcasts.apple.com/au/podcast/midday-marketing-with-lynn/id1501068720","stitcher_link":"https://www.stitcher.com/podcast/radio-media-pty-ltd-2/midday-marketing-with-lynn","googlepodcast":"https://playmusic.app.goo.gl/?ibi=com.google.PlayMusic&isi=691797987&ius=googleplaymusic&apn=com.google.android.music&link=https://play.google.com/music/m/Iyzungfizezvg6vhqrlxzgc3wga?t%3DMidday_Marketing_With_Lynn%26pcampaignid%3DMKT-na-all-co-pr-mu-pod-16"},{"_id":"5e6630d3dfa2e000f814f85a","title":"Popculture News and Reviews","link":"http://drn1.com.au/shows/popculture","icon":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/popculturenewsandreviews/Logo.png","banner":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/popculturenewsandreviews/POPBANNER%20EVERY%20MONDAY.png","url":"popculture","category":"Society &amp; Culture","subcategory":"","description":"Every Monday Anthony and Seve will be bringing you all the news in the world of Pop Culture! Movies, TV Shows, Video Games and Comics, if you’re a fan of it, we’ll be talking about it!  Listen live at 4pm on DRN1 or download the podcast!","subtitle":"Every Monday Anthony and Seve will be bringing you all the news in the world of Pop Culture! Movies, TV Shows, Video Games and Comics, if you’re a fan of it, we’ll be talking about it!  Listen live at 4pm on DRN1 or download the podcast!","summary":"Every Monday Anthony and Seve will be bringing you all the news in the world of Pop Culture! Movies, TV Shows, Video Games and Comics, if you’re a fan of it, we’ll be talking about it!  Listen live at 4pm on DRN1 or download the podcast!","explicit":"no","station":["DRN1"],"day-air":["Monday"],"starttime-air":["16:00:00"],"endtime-air":["17:00:00"],"active":true,"itunes_link":"https://podcasts.apple.com/au/podcast/popculture-news-and-reviews/id1502095026","stitcher_link":"","googlepodcast":"https://playmusic.app.goo.gl/?ibi=com.google.PlayMusic&isi=691797987&ius=googleplaymusic&apn=com.google.android.music&link=https://play.google.com/music/m/I6dv4egekke5hmrd46haqw2r4sq?t%3DPopculture_News_and_Reviews%26pcampaignid%3DMKT-na-all-co-pr-mu-pod-16"},{"_id":"5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc","title":"Bounce Back","link":"http://drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback","icon":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/bounceback_logo.png","banner":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/BounceBackBanner.jpg","url":"bounceback","category":"Comedy","subcategory":"","description":"Get ready for a laugh or two with Bounce Back with Yvonne Fletcher. Each week she invites two comedians to chat about their comedy past and future. This show will have you laughing all the way home.","subtitle":"Get ready for a laugh or two with Bounce Back with Yvonne Fletcher. Each week she invites two comedians to chat about their comedy past and future. This show will have you laughing all the way home.","summary":"Get ready for a laugh or two with Bounce Back with Yvonne Fletcher. Each week she invites two comedians to chat about their comedy past and future. This show will have you laughing all the way home.","explicit":"true","station":["DRN1"],"day-air":["Thursday"],"starttime-air":["19:00:00"],"endtime-air":["20:00:00"],"active":true,"itunes_link":"https://podcasts.apple.com/au/podcast/bounce-back/id1513169177","stitcher_link":""},{"_id":"5f27db2367cf8ffcc3a593d0","title":"Balls","link":"http://drn1.com.au/shows/balls","icon":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/Balls/ballslogo.jpg","banner":"https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/Balls/ballslogo.jpg","url":"balls","category":"Sports","subcategory":"Basketball","description":"Join BALLS every week as we have conversations with Trainers, Coaches, Athletes and others involved in the West Australian Basketball community and culture","subtitle":"Join BALLS every week as we have conversations with Trainers, Coaches, Athletes and others involved in the West Australian Basketball community and culture","summary":"Join BALLS every week as we have conversations with Trainers, Coaches, Athletes and others involved in the West Australian Basketball community and culture","explicit":"false","station":["DRN1"],"day-air":["Saturday"],"starttime-air":["13:30:00"],"endtime-air":["14:30:00"],"active":true,"itunes_link":"","stitcher_link":""}]}
```

from
https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/programs/DRN1

I thought this would work.

```
import SwiftUI


struct Post : Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title : String
    var icon : String
}

class Api {
    func getPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/programs/DRN1") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data['programs']!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                completion(posts)
            }
            
        }
    .resume()
    }
}
```

however I am getting an error, how do I get the data inside programs?

Comment: How this refers to SwiftUI framework? I don't think it should be tagged [swiftui] - it is just regular swift code with URLSession/JSONDecoder from Foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top level of your `JSON` has a parameter `programs` which in turn contains an array. You should update your code like this

```
import SwiftUI

// Add this top level struct to
// decode properly
struct Post: Codable {
    var programs: [Program]
}

struct Program: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title : String
    var icon : String
}

class Api {
    // Update this to return an array of Program
    func getPosts(completion: @escaping ([Program]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/programs/DRN1") else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            // Based on the updated structs, you would no
            // longer be decoding an array
            let post = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: data['programs']!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                // The array is stored under programs now
                completion(post.programs)
            }
            
        }
    .resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[Program]' to expected argument type '[Post]'

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I've updated the answer. Replace `func getPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ())` with `func getPosts(completion: @escaping ([Program]) -> ())`

Comment: Thank you, I can see the advantage of this way of coding - But I have to be honest it way out of my norm. I am trying now to get this into a Hstack view and it just failing. 

But thank you for this answer - It does work.

Comment: For `Codable` to work, the `struct` or `class` has to be mappable directly to JSON. If you require any changes, you can write your own `encode` and `decode` methods to override `Codable`'s default implementation

Comment: Honestly I am starting to feel it is easier to stick with UIKit

Comment: `Codable` protocol works the same whether you use `SwiftUI` or `UIKit`. It is a protocol to convert JSON into a `struct` or `class`. Having said that, `SwiftUI` is more inclined towards `MVVM` whereas `UIKit` is more inclined towards `MVC`. I personally would make a decision between `UIKit` & `SwiftUI` based on the design pattern since `Codable` does not have any bearing on either one

Comment: Sorry link was wrong - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451123/swiftui-json-wont-print-title

Comment: sorry to bother you any chance you could show how to put the data in a HStack please. been 2 hours and can't get it to work.

Comment: What sort of data do you want to put in the HStack? How do you want to configure the HStack? A lot more information is required